# PyQT5 show spend time on window

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I have QMediaPlayer and QVideoWidget for playing videos with spended time QLineEdit and finish program QLineEdit. I am trying to do make a counter that show how many minutes user spended on this program and when user reachs finish program limit pop-up a dialog. For that I create a thread function:

```
def update_video_timer(self):
    end_time = int(self.end_time.text())
    start_time = 0
    while start_time <= end_time:
        self.spended_time.setText(str(start_time))
        start_time = start_time + 1
        # minutes
        time.sleep(60)

    # reachs limit
    self.mediaPlayer.pause()
    dlg = QDialog(self)
    dlg.setWindowTitle("YOUR TIME HAS FINISHED!")
    dlg.exec_()
```

I call this function when first video started to play:

```
from threading import Thread
Thread(target=self.update_video_timer())
```

But the problem is when video starts to play, program is freezing. Any help and/or improvement of my code is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks in a GUI must be asynchronous and invoke synchronous tasks that consume very little time. If synchronous tasks consume a lot of time then they must be executed in another thread. In your case it is not necessary to use while + time.sleep() but a counter with a QTimer is enough and thus it is not necessary to use threads:

```py
    self.timer = QTimer(self, interval=60 * 1000)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timeout)
    self.start_time = 0
    self.end_time = 0

def start(self):
    try:
        self.end_time = int(self.end_time.text())
    except ValueError as e:
        print("error")
    else:
        self.timer.start()

def on_timeout(self):
    if self.start_time <= self.end_time:
        self.start_time += 1
        self.spended_time.setText(str(self.start_time))
    else:
        self.timer.stop()
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        dlg = QDialog(self)
        dlg.setWindowTitle("YOUR TIME HAS FINISHED!")
        dlg.exec_()
```